# How to automatically change facebook cover?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to ask how can I automatically change facebook cover photo? I know it's possible, but I don't know how to do it. Any ideas, tips or tricks?

Thank you!

examples: https://www.facebook.com/zaraguza or https://www.facebook.com/adbeedigital (likes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a cover photo for a Page by issuing an HTTP POST to /PAGE_ID with a Page Access Token.

with following parameters :

cover          --- The ID of the photo

offset_y       --- The percentage offset from top (0-100). The default value is 50

no_feed_story  --- The flag indicating whether or not to create a story. The default value is   false

checkout this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) ( under Setting a Cover Photo ) for more details.

Comment: Is it still possible? Is the access_token remain forever?

Answer (score 1):

i have see the facebook page you gave, but i dont see any changing in there. Alaways static

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/adbeedigital Like the page, wait few second(minutes max). F5